# why did this multiplication "628.93*100" give me this result "62892.99999999999"?

Tags: javascript

Today i had an issue on js with that operation,  this happens when I multiply on the web console and have no idea why it happens!

Thanks!

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, traduce tu pregunta y modificala por favor agregando más información revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Ah muchas gracias, en realidad creí que lo verían de cualquier comunidad entonces lo puse en inglés, de todas formas incluyeron una pregunta similar que respondió mi duda, Gracias!!

Comment: En este sitio puedes escribir con confianza en español, solo recuerda aportar datos como lo que has tratado o investigado @André saludos.